# You've been signed in with a temporary profile windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-server-2012, roaming-profiles

We've got roaming profiles from a Windows Server 2012 AD controller, and several windows 7 machines which log in and out fine.

We have one problem machine, a Windows 8.1 laptop which constantly brings up the error "You've been signed in with a temporary profile". I've followed the steps as listed here: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/38817-you-ve-been-signed-temporary-profile-fix.html but the issue returns after restarting the machine. The same profile signs in fine in Windows 7, but no matter which user we try, the same error comes up on the Windows 8.1 Machine

We've tried wiping the laptop and reinstalling windows 8.1 but the problem persists. This is very frustrating and Microsoft support has been terrible.

Anyone have any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profiles from one version of Windows are not compatible with other versions. You need to create separate profile folders for each platform. Please see [Microsoft article KB2890783](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2890783) for a hotfix and needed registry entry.

Answer (score 0):

After the laptop wipe and reinstall, I assume you kept the laptop computer name the same after the wipe and only reset the AD computer account for this laptop? 
If so...
Next step, I would remove the laptop from AD entirely by first changing the laptop to a non-existent workgroup, reboot, then delete the AD computer account for this laptop from the server. Reboot the server.
Now add the laptop back into AD and into the domain, both physically and logically.

If that does not solve it, I would do again what I said above but this time with a newly wiped laptop. Instead of trying to find the problem, many times it's much better to start from a clean slate (depends on the extent of the problem, of course)
There is some corruption between the server and laptop profile settings for the computer AD entry.

Comment: Hi The laptop was removed from AD prior to being wiped and re-added with a new name after the wipe.